# How can we determine in onPause() if an application/activity is going into the background (onStop) or will be destroyed (onDestroy)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I recently had a telephonic interview session and the interviewer asked a really peculiar question. He wanted to know if we can, by any means, know if an activity/application will be just stopped (onStop) only or be destroyed (onStop then onDestroy) before it even happens , when the flow is in the onPause method.

I mean the execution will be inside onPause and from there itself you can tell if onDestroy(aplication closed) or just onStop (backgrounded).

Could not find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Short answer, no, you can't tell.  It is possible for your activity to be killed, when it is in the background after `onPause()` with no further callbacks to you.  `onDestroy()` is only guaranteed if you `finish()` the activity.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you're looking for `isFinishing()`.

If this is true, the activity is in the process of completely finishing. Usually this is checked from `onPause()`

[Android isFinishing documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing())

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  This only distinguishes between a pause and a stop.  It does not indicate if the activity is being destroyed, which can happen without any callbacks.

Comment: kevskree's answer was partially of what I wanted. Thanks